# how to add values one by one in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to add 8 values of the clicked buttons in an array.

When a user will press any button the id/value against that button stored in an array but my array only save 1st value in the array at array [0].

How to insert other values in an array?

Here is the code:

```js
function reply_click(obj) {
  var id = [obj.id];
  for (i = 0; i <= id; i++) {
    alert(id);
  }
}

var arr = [id];

alert(arr);

if (id[0] == "1") {
  alert(6666666666);
}

if (id[0] == "2") {
  id[0] = 1;
  id[1] = 2;
  alert(777777777777);
}


if (id[0] == "3") {
  id[0] = 1;
  id[1] = 2;
  id[2] = 3;
  alert('login');
}

alert(id);

$(document).on('click', '.btn', function() {

  alert($(this).val());

  var myvalues = $(this).val();
  alert(myvalues);

  var cars = [myvalues, "myvaluesv", "Toyota"];
  alert(cars);
  var x = cars.length;
  alert(x);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="1" onClick="reply_click(this)">1</button>
<button id="2" onClick="reply_click(this)">2</button>
<button id="3" onClick="reply_click(this)">3</button>

<button id="tahira" name="btn" class="btn" value="tahirahassan">hi tahira</button>
<button id="sobia" name="btn" class="btn" value="sobia">hi sobia</button>
<form action="testingjquery.php" method="post">
  <input type="submit" id="btn1" class="btn111" name="val1" value=" i am tahira" />
  <input type="submit" id="btn2" class="btn112" name="val1" value="hassan" />
</form>
```

Comment: `arr.push("new_value")`;

Comment: but how to save the each clicked button value in one array?As i get value by $(document).on('click', '.btn', function(){ 

   alert($(this).val());
    
  var myvalues=$(this).val();
   alert(myvalues);
  
var cars =[myvalues, "myvaluesv", "Toyota"];
  alert(cars);
         var x = cars.length;
      alert(x);
          });

Comment: are you sure? your code  is error free?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## You can try this

```
     <html>
      <head>
         <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script>
          var arr=new Array;
          //unique object variable
          var trackObject = {};
          function reply_click(obj){
              var id = [obj.id];

                //check value is not duplicated 
                 if(!trackObject.hasOwnProperty(id)){
                    trackObject[id] = 1;
                    for(i=1;i<=id;i++){
                      arr.push(i);
                    }
                 }
                console.log(arr);

          } 
          $(document).ready(function(){
              $(".btn").click(function(){
                var myvalues=$(this).val();
                //check value is not duplicated
                 if(!trackObject.hasOwnProperty(myvalues)){
                    trackObject[myvalues] = 1;
                    arr.push(myvalues);

                  }
                  console.log(arr);

              });
          });
          // attach the .equals method to Array's prototype to call it on any array
      Array.prototype.equals = function (array) {
          // if the other array is a falsy value, return
          if (!array)
              return false;

          // compare lengths - can save a lot of time 
          if (this.length != array.length)
              return false;

          for (var i = 0, l=this.length; i < l; i++) {
              // Check if we have nested arrays
              if (this[i] instanceof Array && array[i] instanceof Array) {
                  // recurse into the nested arrays
                  if (!this[i].equals(array[i]))
                      return false;       
              }           
              else if (this[i] != array[i]) { 
                  return false;   
              }           
          }       
          return true;
      }  
      function compare(){

        result=arr.equals([1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, "tahirahassan", "sobia"]);
        alert(result);
      }
          </script>
          </head>


          <body >
              <p>Click on this paragraph.</p>
            <button id="1" onClick="reply_click(this)">1</button>
          <button id="2" onClick="reply_click(this)">2</button>
           <button id="3" onClick="reply_click(this)">3</button>

        <button id="tahira" name="btn1" class="btn" value="tahirahassan" >hi tahira</button>
       <button id="sobia" name="btn2" class="btn" value="sobia" >hi sobia</button>
         <form action="testingjquery.php" method="post">
          <input type="submit" id="btn1" class="btn111" name="val1" value=" i am tahira"/>
          <input type="submit" id="btn2" class="btn112" name="val1" value="hassan" />
        </form>
        <button id="compare" onClick="compare()">compare</button>

      </body>

      </html>
```

there is some useful link for you [push-array](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) and [unique-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array)

Comment: it works but now how to compare the final array with static value

Comment: yes you can...your final array is global so you get anywhere in our script.btw can you say more specific your needed...then i can help you

Comment: i want to declare one more array  and if the entered values in the array by clicking on buttons equal to new array then move to next page :                                                                      var arrt=new Array;
 arrt= ["cat", "lion", "dog", 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3];                and we

Comment: do you want to compare two array?

Comment: yes i want to compare arr array with arrt if both same then alert or move to next page

Comment: i got you answer but  how can send you?

Comment: add those line with in script

Comment: i updated the code plz check and let me know..be careful about   compare sequence in array

Comment: which code? can you send the code

Comment: which one i uploaded by post yesterday. pz check accepted answare

Comment: thanks got it.i waNT to ask one more thing is there any way to automatically compare array after 8 entries in arr array without pressing compare button?

Comment: yes you can..plz see compare function in your script. result=arr.equals([1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, "tahirahassan", "sobia"]); u can change here ..but be careful about sequence otherwise you get confuse

Comment: got your point but how to run compare function after 8 entries in arr array without pressing compare button

Comment: you can call compare function in many way..you can call compare function within  $(".btn").click(function(){....function

Comment: u can use if(!trackObject.hasOwnProperty(myvalues)){
                    trackObject[myvalues] = 1;
                    arr.push(myvalues);
                    compare();
                  }

Comment: thanks a lot .working

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.prototype.push()` method to add a new value at the end of the array. It will also return the new length.

`cars.push(myvalues, "myvaluesv", "Toyota")` for your example. You can push any datatype into an array.